# How to check the CRC of the function in C++

Tags: c++, function, disassembly, crc

Is it possible to count the CRC of code in the memory of the function in the runtime?

I have a function that compares user's password with the secret password. If I check the CRC of *all commands in function*, I will be able to understand if the code of the function was overwritten in disassembler.

For now, I've tried using the Boost::crc but I'm not sure, how can I pass the function into the `crc_32_type` object.

This is not working (at least, returns a new result every time I run the program):

```
void myFunction() {...};

auto GetCrc32() -> decltype(boost::crc_32_type().checksum()){
    std::function<void()> func = myFunction;

    boost::crc_32_type result;
    result.process_bytes(&func, sizeof(func));
    return result.checksum();
}
```

Comment: All someone need to do is to modify your CRC function to always return true. These sort of code checks can always be bypassed.  All this does is to slightly increase the effort required.

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes, but I need it as a part of the security in my program.

Comment: My point is that trying to do this does not increase the security in any meaningful way.  You are trying to check for machine-code changes,  so the 1st change I would make is to amend the code doing the checking.

Comment: functions don't have CRCs, so there is nothing to check against. Even if they did, there is no way to query the *size* of a function (in fact, the compiler is not even required to layout a function sequentially at all).  The correct way to detect if your code has been modified is to [*sign the code*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing) after compiling it, and then verify the signature at runtime, but that won't detect modifications made after the verification is performed.

Comment: To echo what @Richard said, this is a fool's errand.  What attacks are you actually worried about?  You'd be better served trying to protect against them, since there are likely better ways to harden your program and environment.

Comment: I have an assignment at the university. This is not my idea. But now I'm confused, maybe I am not getting this part right.

Comment: @Alvov1 either you are misunderstanding what the assignment wants, or the teacher is not explaining the assignment correctly, or has simply given you an impossible task. It would help if you would share what the assignment *actually* is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no portable way to find or access the compiled function code during execution.

If code can be modified maliciously, then the code checking the code can also be modified maliciously to not detect changes, making the exercise entirely pointless.

Lastly, a CRC is easily spoofed, so the code could easily be modified in a way that leaves the CRC unchanged.

None of what you're trying to do makes any sense.